# jQuery (highlight text after creating input)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm very new to jQuery and js. Here is question.
I need to create a button which adds an input field and then highlights all expressions in given text matching with text in input.
I have no problem with adding new input field. I also found solution for highlighting areas in text. The problem is I can't combine these 2 things in one.
So I have following: if there is already input field on page and I type smth here, the matching parts from text are highlighted. But if i use button to add new input field and then type anything there, there is no highlight. 
Question may be quite silly, so can you at least tell me where exactly I can read about it? I'm really new here and have no clue why it's happening.
https://jsfiddle.net/0on93vrv/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//var max_fields      = ; //maximum input boxes allowed
var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

var x = 1; //initlal text box count
$(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if(x < 2){ //max input box allowed
       x++; //text box increment
    $(wrapper).append('<div><input id="input" type="text" name="mytext[]"/>     </div>');
    //add input box
   }
});
$("input").on("input.highlight", function() {
// Determine specified search term
var searchTerm = $(this).val();
// Highlight search term inside a specific context
$("#context").unmark().mark(searchTerm);
}).trigger("input.highlight").focus();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `(document).on` for dynamically created elements like so:

```
$( document ).on( "input.highlight", "input", function() {
// Determine specified search term
var searchTerm = $(this).val();
// Highlight search term inside a specific context
$("#context").unmark().mark(searchTerm);
}).trigger("input.highlight").focus();
});
```

Here is an updated fiddle [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/cy5pk9L0/)

Answer (score 1):

The way you add the `input.highlight` event listener to the `input` elements

```
$("input").on("input.highlight", function() {
    ....
});
```

Make it so that the callback function will only be triggered by `input.highlight` events on `input`s that are already in the DOM.

Try this if you want to trigger the callback on `input`s that are dynamically added to the DOM:

```
$("body").on("input.highlight", "input", function() {
    ....
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to have dynamic trigger event.. have a look over..

Replace your

```
$("input").on("input.highlight", function() {
```

with

```
 $("body").on("input.highlight", "input", function() {
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    //var max_fields      = ; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID
    
    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < 2){ //max input box allowed
           x++; //text box increment
        $(wrapper).append('<div><input id="input" type="text" name="mytext[]"/></div>');
        //add input box
       }
    });
    $("body").on("input.highlight", "input", function() {
   
    // Determine specified search term
    var searchTerm = $(this).val();
    // Highlight search term inside a specific context
    $("#context").unmark().mark(searchTerm);
  }).trigger("input.highlight").focus();
    });
```

```css
mark {
  background: orange;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/mark.js/7.0.0/jquery.mark.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="test">
<div id="context">
  Some text which i want to check for matches
</div>
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
    <div class="color_input"><input  type="text" name="mytext[]"></div>
</div>
```